# How to divide string into two parts using regex in java?

Tags: java

```
String strArray="135(i),15a,14(g)(q)12,67dd(),kk,159"; //splited by ','
```

divide string after first occurrence of alphanumeric value/character

expected output :

```
    original         expected o/p
    15a              s1=15   s2=a
    67dd()           s1=67   s2=dd()
    kk               s1=""   s2=kk
    159              s1=159  s2=""
```

Please help me................

Comment: why do you ignore `135(i)` `14(g)(q)12` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the group-method of Pattern/Matcher:

```
String strArray = "135(i),15a,14(g)(q)12,67dd(),kk,159";//splited by ','
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<digits>\\d*)(?<chars>[^,]*)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strArray);
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (!matcher.group().isEmpty()) //omit empty groups
        System.out.println(matcher.group() + " : " + matcher.group("digits") + " - " + matcher.group("chars"));
}
```

The method group(String name) gives you the String found in the pattern's parenthesis with the specific name (here it is 'digits' or 'chars') within the match.
The method group(int i) would give you the String found in the i-th parenthesis of the pattern within the match.

See the Oracle tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ for more examples of using regex in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Pattern` and a `Matcher` to find the first index of a letter preceded by a number and split at that position.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String[] inputs = { "15a", "67dd()", "kk", "159" };
    for (String input : inputs) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=[0-9])[a-zA-Z]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        System.out.println("Input: " + input);
        if (m.find()) {
            int splitIndex = m.end();
            // System.out.println(splitIndex);
            System.out.println("1.\t"+input.substring(0, splitIndex - 1));
            System.out.println("2.\t"+input.substring(splitIndex - 1));
        } else {
            System.out.println("1.");
            System.out.println("2.\t"+input);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Input: 15a
1.  15
2.  a
Input: 67dd()
1.  67
2.  dd()
Input: kk
1.  
2.  kk
Input: 159
1.
2.  159
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher`

```
String strArray="135(i),15a,14(g)(q)12,67dd(),kk,159";
String arr[] = strArray.split(",");
  for (String s : arr) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([0-9]*)([^0-9]*)").matcher(s);
    System.out.println("String in = " + s);
    if(m.matches()){
      System.out.println(" s1: " + m.group(1));
      System.out.println(" s2: " + m.group(2));
    } else {
      System.out.println(" unmatched");
    }
}
```

**outputs:**

```
String in = 135(i)
 s1: 135
 s2: (i)
String in = 15a
 s1: 15
 s2: a
String in = 14(g)(q)12
 unmatched
String in = 67dd()
 s1: 67
 s2: dd()
String in = kk
 s1: 
 s2: kk
String in = 159
 s1: 159
 s2:
```

Note how `'14(g)(q)12'` is not matched. It's not clear what the OP's required output is in this instance (or if a comma is missing from this portion of the example input string).